# Visual Studio Dependency Validation does not check (ignores) xaml/WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, validation, xaml

I am extensively using [Depency Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/validate-code-with-layer-diagrams?view=vs-2022) diagrams in a big WPF application to enforce layer separation using the standard NuGet package `Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers` in its current version 0.11.0.

I thought the validation works as expected (and also tested it back in the day)... but now I had to find out: **Validation does not check xaml usages!**

First I thought it is an issue of our big application. But a small test app with current technology (current VisualStudio 2022, WPF and .NET 7) shows the same issue:

This default WPF app with

- one additional `Views` project with one Button (`MyButton`) in it
- the `Validation` project with one dependency diagram:

[image: solution]

`MainWindow` uses `MyButton` in XAML:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="DepVal1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Views;assembly=Views"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!--  But this usage is ignored by the validation!  -->
        <views:MyButton Content="Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and also in code-behind:

```
namespace DepVal1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // This usage leads to an validation error when uncommented
            //var test = new Views.MyButton();
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments: The usage `var test = new Views.MyButton();` in code-behind gets caught by the validation (Build error [DV0001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/validate-code-with-layer-diagrams?view=vs-2022#resolve-layer-validation-errors)). The `<views:MyButton Content="Test" />` isn't!

The diagram itself is quite simple:

[image: diagram]

Both projects/csproj (`DepVal1` and `Views`) have the necessary settings of course:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\Validation\DependencyValidation1.layerdiagram" Link="DependencyValidation1.layerdiagram">
        <Visible>False</Visible>
    </AdditionalFiles>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers" Version="0.11.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Am I missing here something? Or is it really a bug in the validation algorithm? If so...how has nobody noticed this before? I couldn't find anything about this issue anywhere...

Thanks
Soko